Block height exceeded - Wormhole - Receiving WETH in Solflare wallet
Sorry if the question has already be submited, but I couldn't find any answer and I'm a bit lost.
I can't finalize the transaction to receive WETH from Wormhole (portalbridge.com) on my Solflare wallet.
Blockheight is exceeded, and no matter how many time I try to approve the transaction the result is the same.
What can I do ?
Thanks

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?

Facing the same issue.
'has expired: block height exceeded.'
Read about "Setting Priority Fee for Your Transaction" from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/issues/1987
Though portalbridge.com doesn't let you increase spendings on priority fee.
